# How to show specific field only to the user profile owner in graphene-django?

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-django

I have the following schema in my `graphene-django` application:

```py
import graphene
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("id", "username", "email")


class Query(object):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType, user_id=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_user(self, info, user_id):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        if info.context.user.id != user_id:
            # If the query didn't access email field -> query is ok
            # If the query tried to access email field -> raise an error
        else:
            # Logged in as the user we're querying -> let the query access all the fields
```

I want to be able to query the schema in the following way:

```
# Logged in as user 1 => no errors, because we're allowed to see all fields
query {
  user (userId: 1) {
    id
    username
    email
  }
}

# Not logged in as user 1 => no errors, because not trying to see email
query {
  user (userId: 1) {
    id
    username
  }
}

# Not logged in as user 1 => return error because accessing email
query {
  user (userId: 1) {
    id
    username
    email
  }
}
```

How can I make it so that only a logged in user can see the `email` field of their own profile and no one else can see the emails of others?

Comment: Take a look at the [authorization example](http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/middleware/#example) of Graphene middleware.

Comment: @TomasLinhart I've gone through that many times, but can't wrap my head around how to do it.

Comment: You are right that using authorization middleware for this case is maybe a bit superfluous. However, the solution depends on if you want to return the user object without `email` field (suggested by the first code block) or raise an error (suggested by the second code block). If the former, just do `user['email'] = None` or `del user['email']` in `if info.context.user.id != user_id:` branch. If the later, raise an exception there.

Comment: @TomášLinhart I edited my graphql and python comments a bit. I want to only raise an error if the query is accessing email and is not logged in to the user. Would you mind expanding your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just doing it like this, where the actual value of `email` is returned when querying one's own info, and `None` is returned for others:

```
import graphene
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("id", "username", "email")

    def resolve_email(self, info):
        if info.context.user.is_authenticated and self.pk == info.context.user.pk:
            return self.email
        else:
            return None


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType, user_id=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_user(self, info, user_id):
        return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the approach I would take based on the comments. The main issue here is to be able to get a list of fields requested by a query in the resolver. For that, I use a code adapted from [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/348#issuecomment-267717809):

```
def get_requested_fields(info):
    """Get list of fields requested in a query."""
    fragments = info.fragments

    def iterate_field_names(prefix, field):
        name = field.name.value
        if isinstance(field, FragmentSpread):
            results = []
            new_prefix = prefix
            sub_selection = fragments[name].selection_set.selections
        else:
            results = [prefix + name]
            new_prefix = prefix + name + '.'
            sub_selection = \
                field.selection_set.selections if field.selection_set else []
        for sub_field in sub_selection:
            results += iterate_field_names(new_prefix, sub_field)
        return results

    results = iterate_field_names('', info.field_asts[0])
    return results
```

The rest should be quite straightforward:

```
import graphene
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType


class AuthorizationError(Exception):
    """Authorization failed."""


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("id", "username", "email")


class Query(object):
    user = graphene.Field(UserType, user_id=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_user(self, info, user_id):
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        if info.context.user.id != user_id:
            fields = get_requested_fields(info)
            if 'user.email' in fields:
                raise AuthorizationError('Not authorized to access user email')
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is wayyy overcomplicated. Just create two ObjectTypes e.g.:

```
class PublicUserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields  = ('id', 'username')

class PrivateUserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
```

Spent over 4 hours trying other solutions before realized it was this simple